# reading raw string from file in C#

Tags: c#, string, rawstring

I have the following raw-string literal : `@"some text ""here"" and some more text"`
Everything works fine when I have this assigned to a string variable in a program. 
But when I put this string - `"some text ""here"" and some more text"` and read it, it is not being recognized as a raw string. 

What should I do to have C# recognize this as a raw-string? Specifically, what is the programmatic equivalent of the '@' specifier used to indicate that the string is a raw-string?

Comment: How do you save it and read it? Do you save in text file, xml...?

Comment: would you care to show your code how you do int presently? otherwise you add there escape character for every quote you have

Comment: A string is a string - if it contains quotes or not. What exactly is the problem you are facing with these strings?

Comment: Hi, the text is in a .txt file which I dont own..I can only read the file..

Comment: OK. And what exactly is the problem in reading the file? If the text contains quotes, the string you get will contain quotes.

Comment: You're confused here. the @ sign is just a way of telling the C# compiler to threat a couple of double quotes as a literal double quote rather than an end- and opening quote for a string (since strings in C# need to reside between double quotes. That's just how the language goes. From a programmatic point of view, there is no need to implement a solution for double quotes (depending on the context), when you put the following text in a text file: <i>"hello"world</i>, and you read the whole bunch in a string using a StreamReader, the double quotes will be interpreted as a literal.

Comment: @Oded the example provided in problem statement is a hypothetical one.. the actual string in file is JSON. the keys are of the form ""key""..after I read the contents of the file, I am not able to deserialize the text back to JSON object

Comment: @Aadith - Why don't you ask about that instead of going into a discussion about literal strings and such? If your file is as defined, it is **not** valid JSON.

Comment: @Oded When I copy th string from file and put it in a program as @"string" , I am able to deserialize it..so the text in file is a valid JSON

Comment: Can you please explain `When I copy th string from file and put it in a program as @"string"`? How do you do that?

Answer (score 2):

why dont you escape it ?

```
"some text \"here\" and some more text"
```

[image]

Comment: the text is not owned by me..i just read it..so not under my control

Answer (score 1):

There's no programmatic equivalent of the `@` specifier. The specifier is used only at *compile* time to convert a verbatim string *literal* to its internal representation. (BTW, the proper name is verbatim string, not raw-string).

Therefore, `str1` and `str2` below represent *exactly* the same string at runtime:

```
string str1 = "some text \"here\" and some more text";
string str2 = @"some text ""here"" and some more text";
```

The one and only difference between them is visible in your source code only. You don't need to apply any kind of programmatic transformation when your read strings from a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you say raw string, you mean literal string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx

Literal strings using the @ symbol are just telling the compiler to literally take the text provided.

As far as I know there is no way to convert a string into the literal version of that string.

But you could easily write that code that replaces double quotes with single quotes.